# Jenkins Groovy code works with "print", throws with "sh"

Tags: jenkins, groovy

This code works:

```groovy
def eventConfig = json root
def jsonStringified = json.toString()
def shCommand = """aws s3api put-bucket-notification-configuration \
  --bucket ${sourceBucket} \
  --cli-input-json '${jsonStringified}'
"""
print shCommand
```

And if I change last line to:

```
sh shCommand
```

It throws `java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.JsonBuilder` with stack trace beginning with:

```
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
```

I have totally no idea why this happens.

Comment: Maybe `${jsonStringified}` contains pretty JSON, so your command breaks using new line? This is the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: You're code assigns a variable to something that isn't serializable.. My guess is the json variable...

Comment: This question is tagged as a jenkins-job-dsl script but the script in your question does not look like a job-dsl job. 

Are you trying to generate a Jenkins job with this code? If you are it is a jenkins job-dsl job and I can help you out immediately. 

If you are writing a Groovy script using the Scriptler  plugin then you should remove the jenkins-job-dsl tag and I can help you out with a bit of research.